# is react supposed to be used on top of handlebars with node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to use react on my node.js website. Im using express and handlebars with this website. Is react supposed to be used on top of all that? Or should i not use handlebars or express with react?

Also what is your opinion on node.js? Is it a declining technology? Is there something else that is better for me to use?

Comment: React is pure front-end code. So you will find that using react you will be using 0% of handlebars since react does not run on node.js at all. React can be served using any static web server such as `express.static` or `nginx` or `apache` etc. React compiles down to a single HTML file and a bunch of browser-side js files. Using react you will find that you will be writing a lot of REST API with express so you will mostly be using `res.json()` and not generate any html in express

Comment: @slebetman, what if I already have an application built with nodejs express handlebars. And want to include some extra features that would require some JS image rendering. Is React a good option to do this?

Comment: You will be replacing most of the handlebars stuff with React's JSX. You maybe can implement just one page in React but React is structured very differently from something like Handlebars. Where handlebars you have different HTML file for each page React is a single page app - so just ONE html file for your entire project. And react's rendering engine will decide what to draw in the browser based on user actions (zero requests to back-end). With React you only serve data, not HTML, to front-end. Usually in JSON format but that's not mandatory. You can use csv or XML if you want

Answer (score 0):

React is a view library. Is mean to be used to build your entire ui.
Then you have two options you can use it to build a SPA - single page application - and consume data through network request to your server or render multiple pages each of those will be a react app.
Node + express are backend tech that can help you to build the server side of a web app here you can create some api endpoints to return data to the server and comunícate with the database.

Node is a very good choice as is still and will be used for long time and many companies.